# Virtualbox in Virtualbox は可能か

Tags: virtualbox

Virtualbox の仮想マシンの中に Virtualbox をインストールして、仮想マシンを立ち上げることは技術的に可能ですか。少し試行錯誤したり、ネットで調べたりしても、成功している例を見つけられずにいるので、そもそもこれは可能なのかしら、と思い質問しています。

### 質問

Virtualbox の中で Virtualbox は使えますか？

- もし可能なら、それをやるにあたって何か気を付けるべきはまる場所などありますか？
- もし不可能なら、それはなぜ不可能ですか？

### 環境

ホスト: Windows 10
ゲスト (1段目): ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VMwareや最近のHyper-VではCPUに搭載された仮想化支援技術をエミュレーションする機能がある（Nested Virtualization）のですが、VirtualBoxにはありません。そのため、VirtualBox上で動かすゲストOSではこのような技術を使うことができません。

じゃあ仮想化支援が使えなければVirtualBoxは全く使えないのかと言えば、多少パフォーマンスは落ちる？ものの、32bit環境の仮想化は行えます。

VT-xが使えない状態だと、仮想マシンの設定で64-bitが選択できないようになります。既に選択されていた場合、仮想マシンの起動時にエラーが出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

OP 追記:

- ゲスト 1 段目: ubuntu/trusty64
- ゲスト 2 段目: ubuntu/trusty32

でもって、 vagrant で動作検証ができました。ゲスト1段目は仮想ディスクを拡張する必要がありましたが。。